# How does an int evaluate as a boolean statement?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

So I was learning Python on Codecademy recently, and I accidentally submitted this

```
    def check_bit4(input):
        if 0b1000 & input:
            return "on"
        else:
            return "off"
```

as my code when it should have been this (the " > 0 " in the if statement was omitted). For some reason, the code above still passed all the given test cases.

```
    def check_bit4(input):
        if 0b1000 & input > 0:
            return "on"
        else:
            return "off"
```

The original prompt asked for a function that would check if the fourth bit was "on". From what I know, the '&' operator should return an int value rather than a boolean value. So, my question is, why does the first program still pass all the test cases?

Comment: Side-note: Don't name variables `input` (or any other name which shadows a built-in). It only leads to tears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zero is considered as falsy value. Other number are considered truth value:

```
>>> bool(1)
True
>>> bool(34)
True
>>> bool(0)
False
```

`0b1000 & input` will return non-zero value if the `input` has the bit set. So the predicate will be considered true if that condition is met.

See [Truth Value Testing - Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth) for more precise definition of truth value.

Comment: Take a look at [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth) in the Python docs for precise definitions of "truthiness" and "falsiness" in Python.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, Thank you for the reference. I updated the answer to include it.